# Connecting Django container to MySQL container in a single AWS ECS Fargate task definition

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a repository [here](https://github.com/ucf/podman-django-template). I am currently struggling with deploying it to AWS ECS. The repository is configured to use Github Actions to build the two containers and then ship them to ECR, then update an ECS task definition to pull the most recent image commit.

I am using ECS Fargate, and am therefore on awsvpc for the network mode.

I tried changing the hostname to localhost. When I do so, I get this error: `MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`

According to comments so far, setting it to localhost will work. However, I still get this error. I have double checked that my settings.py and .env file have localhost as the DB_HOST.

What I've tried is visible at [the repository here](https://github.com/ucf/podman-django-template)

Comment: it would be  `localhost`

Comment: In the original post I noted that I tried localhost as well but that did not work. It gives this error: `MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`

Comment: then use `127.0.0.1`

Comment: If anyone else has this problem, this worked for me ^

Comment: if you had searched for your error you find hundreds of the same aqnswer

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, the name of the DB_HOST in the settings.py should be the name of the container when they are in the same task definition.

No that is incorrect. When you are using `awsvpc` network mode for your containers, which is the only option on Fargate, then the `DB_HOST` setting should be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: As I said in my post above, I tried localhost as well but that did not work. It gives this error: `MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`

Comment: You didn't include that error in your question. That error indicates that you aren't setting the `DB_HOST` value correctly, and Django is getting an empty value for that. It is trying to connect over a Unix file socket, instead of using the `localhost` address. If you are just setting `DB_HOST` environment variable in ECS, you still have to modify your Django settings.py file to actually read that value from the environment variable. Please edit your question to show exactly what you are doing if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the original post. I am setting both DB_HOST in .env and settings.py to localhost. However, I still seem to get the error of `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`

Comment: It worked when I used 127.0.0.1. Thank you so much!